# LineageOS - bug when text is copied

Tags: bugs, lineageos

I upgrade my phone to LineageOS 14. When I try copy text (long press) or if i copy text to clipboard by button and try paste him - any application is crashed.

```
Drawable cannot be cast to VectorDrawable
```

Why it does?

Micromax Q415, default android lollipop, flash rom portable

Comment: Brand/model? I have *10* LOS 14.1 devices on my hand now and none exhibit this - looks device-specific.

Comment: You should probably [report the bug on their bug tracker](https://wiki.lineageos.org/bugreport-howto.html) because we might not have any solution for this.

Comment: I known. People make port rom for my device. It bug porting process. I flash new rom with bug fix

Comment: It is occurring for me in second user profile. Not able to paste.